# Turn "She made me wait for two hours" into passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

> She made me wait for two hours.

How to change this sentence into passive voice?
I changed it like this:

> I was made to wait for two hours.

What are your views?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

"wait" cannot be made passive. 
To be made passive, a verb must have an actor and something that is acted upon.
Verbs like "wait, sleep" and others have an actor -- the person doing the waiting or the sleeping -- but not a object of the action. 
That is, you don't "wait something" or "sleep something," so, they can't be made passive.

Comment: The verb being made passive in the example is *made*, not *wait*.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. For instance, a verb very close to "wait" which is "await" sounds natural in passive form. And here are many examples of that: https://ludwig.guru/s/is+awaited+by

Answer (score 2):

> She made me wait for two hours.
>
> How to change this sentence into passive voice? I changed it like
>   this:
>
> I was made to wait for two hours.

Your answer is correct but you have left out 'she'.

To complete it you need, "I was made to wait for two hours by her."

Answer (score -3):

user2036 is correct, but a pseudo-passive construction is possible. "Waiting for her for two hours did not improve my opinion of her." Note that there is now another verb to be considered, but the emphasis has changed. Now it is the condition of being made to wait which is emphasized, rather than the subject.

Comment: I'm confused.  Whatever I wrote is it mistaken?